# very simple php form - one field not submitting

Tags: php, forms

I am making a simple registration form and cannot get one of the select fields to submit. My HTML and PHP all validates fine can anyone please help? My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php

$where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

// Checkbox handling
$field_9_opts = $_POST['field_9'][0];

mail("me@mymail.co.uk","A message from the  Website","A message from the Website:

Their name:  " . $_POST['field_1'] . " 
Their email address:  " . $_POST['field_2'] . " 
Their contact number:  " . $_POST['field_3'] . " 
The customer would prefer to be contacted:  " . $_POST['field_4'] . " 
The type of property the customer is interested in:  " . $_POST['field_5'] . " 
Their price range:  " . $_POST['field_6'] . " 
Their reason for purchase:  " . $_POST['field_7'] . "
They heard about Parkway Newbury from:  " . $_POST['field_8'] . " 
Keep me updated on news on Parkway Living, Newbury:  $field_9_opts 

");

include("confirm.html");

?>
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="processor.php">
<ul id="mainForm_1">

<li id="fieldBox_1">
<label>Your name&nbsp;*</label>
<input type="text" name="field_1" id="field_1" size="20" value="" />
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_2">
<label>Your email address&nbsp;*</label>
<input type="text" name="field_2" id="field_2" size="20" value="" />
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_3">
<label>Your contact number&nbsp;*</label>
<input type="text" name="field_3" id="field_3" size="20" value="" />
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_4">
<label>I would prefer to be contacted&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_4" id="field_4">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="In the morning">In the morning</option>
    <option value="In the afternoon">In the afternoon</option>
    <option value="In the evening">In the evening</option>
    <option value="Anytime">Anytime</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_5">
<label>Property type&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_5" id="field_5">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="Duplex">Duplex</option>
    <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_6">
<label>Prices from&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_6" id="field_6">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="upto &pound;200,000">upto &pound;200,000</option>
    <option value="&pound;200,000 - &pound;300,000">&pound;200,000 - &pound;300,000</option>
    <option value="&pound;300,000 - &pound;400,000">&pound;300,000 - &pound;400,000</option>
    <option value="Above &pound;400,000">Above &pound;400,000</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_7">
<label>Reason for purchase&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_7" id="field_7">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="Moving into the area">Moving into the area</option>
    <option value="First time buyer">First time buyer</option>
    <option value="Downsizing">Downsizing</option>
    <option value="Need more space">Need more space</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_8">
<label>Where did you hear about Parkway Living?&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_8" id="field_8">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="Website">Website</option>
    <option value="National advertising">National Advertising</option>
    <option value="Local advertising">Local Advertising</option>
    <option value="Recommendation">Recommendation</option>
    <option value="Selling agent">Selling agent</option>
    <option value="Site visit">Site visit</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_9">
<label>Keep me updated on news on Parkway Living, Newbury&nbsp;*</label>
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_9[]" id="field_9_option_1" value="yes" />
</span>
</li>

<li>
<input id="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

The field that will not submit is field 8. I would appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would probably help to have the code for the form as well.

Comment: @Jake, @Alexander I have amended my post to include the HTML - thanks

Comment: I can't see any problems. Please show a `print_r($_POST);` after you've selected a value in field 8

Comment: @Pekka sorry I don't what this means I am very much a PHP beginner. How do I do that?

Comment: @mtwallet in the PHP script, do on the first line `print_r($_POST); die();` go to the browser's "View Source" window and copy+paste what's in there. It'll show you the raw list of fields submitted through the form

Comment: In the begin of script make `print_r($_POST);` and give us your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select name should be `field_8[]`

Comment: No, you only need that if you want to allow multiple selections.

Comment: The []-suffix is only necessary when you need to handle multiple-choice(s). // beaten by 14 sec >.<

Comment: @poke Right you are, no need to use the [], that is used to pass multiple values as an array.

Comment: Tried this and it seems to have worked - Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I copied and pasted your HTML in a simple template and it works like a charm. Sure you copied and pasted it correct?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="sv">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php

if (!empty($_POST))
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<ul id="mainForm_1">

<li id="fieldBox_1">
<label>Your name&nbsp;*</label>
<input type="text" name="field_1" id="field_1" size="20" value="" />
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_2">
<label>Your email address&nbsp;*</label>
<input type="text" name="field_2" id="field_2" size="20" value="" />
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_3">
<label>Your contact number&nbsp;*</label>
<input type="text" name="field_3" id="field_3" size="20" value="" />
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_4">
<label>I would prefer to be contacted&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_4" id="field_4">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="In the morning">In the morning</option>
    <option value="In the afternoon">In the afternoon</option>
    <option value="In the evening">In the evening</option>
    <option value="Anytime">Anytime</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_5">
<label>Property type&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_5" id="field_5">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="Duplex">Duplex</option>
    <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
    <option value="Both">Both</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_6">
<label>Prices from&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_6" id="field_6">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="upto &pound;200,000">upto &pound;200,000</option>
    <option value="&pound;200,000 - &pound;300,000">&pound;200,000 - &pound;300,000</option>
    <option value="&pound;300,000 - &pound;400,000">&pound;300,000 - &pound;400,000</option>
    <option value="Above &pound;400,000">Above &pound;400,000</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_7">
<label>Reason for purchase&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_7" id="field_7">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="Moving into the area">Moving into the area</option>
    <option value="First time buyer">First time buyer</option>
    <option value="Downsizing">Downsizing</option>
    <option value="Need more space">Need more space</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_8">
<label>Where did you hear about Parkway Living?&nbsp;*</label>
<select name="field_8" id="field_8">
    <option value="">Please select from the list</option>
    <option value="Website">Website</option>
    <option value="National advertising">National Advertising</option>
    <option value="Local advertising">Local Advertising</option>
    <option value="Recommendation">Recommendation</option>
    <option value="Selling agent">Selling agent</option>
    <option value="Site visit">Site visit</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</li>

<li id="fieldBox_9">
<label>Keep me updated on news on Parkway Living, Newbury&nbsp;*</label>
<span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="field_9[]" id="field_9_option_1" value="yes" />
</span>
</li>

<li>
<input id="saveForm" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</li>
</ul>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Selecting the 2nd value (Website) generates this output:

```
Array
(
    [field_1] => 
    [field_2] => 
    [field_3] => 
    [field_4] => 
    [field_5] => 
    [field_6] => 
    [field_7] => 
    [field_8] => Website
)
```

So it works.

Comment: If I run this code you pasted here everything seems to submit fine, except that field_9 should not be [] but used plainly as the others.